# Binding AAR library to Xamarin.Android, metadata.xml template

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, java-binding

I am creating a binding library for Xamarin.Android from a java AAR file.

Here is the code actually generated after the compilation :

```
   public interface IParent
   {
   }

   public interface IChild : IParent
   {
   }

   public interface IGetter
   {
       IParent Attribute { get; }
   }

   public class MyClass : IGetter
   {
       public IChild Attribute { get; }    //Not allowed in C# but allowed in Java
   }
```

The generated code is the basic translation from Java to C#, but is not valid and does not compile.

I would like to modify the Metadata.xml file (or any other) to tell the compilator to generate the following code instead :

```
public interface IParent
{
}

public interface IChild : IParent
{
}


public interface IGetter<T> where T : IParent
{
    T Attribute { get; }
}

public class MyClass : IGetter<IChild>
{
    public IChild Attribute { get; }   
}
```

How could I do please ?
I have read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata) but can't achieve it :-(

Thanks a lot for any help !!

Comment: From [managedReturn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata#managedreturn), you can try to change return type to `IParent` in `MyClass` class.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Thank you ! If I change the Attribute type from IChild to IParent in MyClass, I will loose data isn't it ? I will not be able to call IParent methods without casting variables which seems to be impossible in the binding project. I will test it, and keep you informed

Comment: yes, you can try to test it, Looking forward to your feedback.